# Sound Juicer does not rescan CDs

Tags: ubuntu, mp3, compact-disc, ripping

I want to rip CD tracks to MP3 to play on a Sandisk MP3 player.  My system is Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty).  I installed Sound Juicer and got it to work on one CD.  But now it is the only CD that SJ will read.  If I load any other CD the track list comes up blank.  "Rescan Disk" does nothing.

Comment: Is your computer connected to the Internet when you rescan?

Comment: do other applications see audio CDs?  do data CDs load ok?  just check to eliminate the possibility of a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to re-install it, use synaptic package manager to re-install it and then install it again, maybe that works?

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command below. Replace /dev/scd0 with the path to your cdrom device.

```
sound-juicer -d /dev/scd0
```

This will ensure sound juicer starts up looking at the correct cdrom (if you have more than one).